# Calculate power with fixed (constant) exponent

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, exponent, numerical-analysis

I have a case where I need to calculate x^y a vast number of times where y is a constant and x is guaranteed to be a valid number.

How can this be done more efficiently that Pow(double x, double y), which will perform various checks and evaluations?

I am looking to precalculate the y transformation.

**EDIT**

Both are real numbers. x = 0 ... 4,000,000,000.

Comment: Is y an integer?  Or at least a rational number?

Comment: What is the range of x ?

Comment: Can you specify in advance which x values you want to solve for? e.g. 0,0.5,1,2.5,...,4000000000 ?

Comment: I won't know in advance what x is. It could be any real number in the range I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember this equiality:

```
x^y = exp(y * ln(x))
```

So you can skip `Pow` and use `exp` and `ln`.

Comment: Not sure if this would be faster. `exp(...)` is still essentially a type of `pow` anyway, just with base `e`.

Comment: @A.R.S. I don't know either... but (maybe I'm wrong) I think `exp` and `ln`  are "hard wired" in many programming language; anyway, that may be the way the machine solves it. On the other hand, `exp` is defined for any real number and `ln` is defined for any positive number, so the validation can be performed "by hand" before the evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. This executes is 67% of the time of Pow.

Comment: @IanC really? wow! Didn't expected that (I'll stad replacing this function in my own code)... By the way, which programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C# under .Net 4.5 64 bit.

Comment: YMMV... I'm getting about 30% speedup running a different test. Not sure why the difference.

Comment: This is significantly less accurate than calling `pow(x,y)`, assuming a good math library, which makes the speedup not terribly surprising.

Comment: @StephenCanon It's all about how much precision are you willing to sacrifice... no free lunch ;-) But, at least in theory, the result should be equal (or close enough)

Comment: @Barranka: Depending on the inputs, this can lose as many bits of accuracy as there are bits in the written exponent of the result.  For example, if the result is on the order of 2^64, this can be the difference between getting an answer with a relative error of approximately 2^-53 and getting and answer with a relative error 2^-47.  For some purposes that's close enough, and for some purposes it isn't.

Comment: @StephenCanon thanks for your note about accuracy. As always, there is no free lunch.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Although y is a constant, x is a variable so there is nothing you can do. I wouldn't worry about it though. the pow() method is very well optimized.

The only thing you can do is to pre calculate the values for many different x's, and save them in a dictionary, unless they can get really big.

Comment: I will use dictionaries where possible. I tested, and they're a bit over 3 times faster than the Pow() function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no faster way in java, since it doesn't support vector operations or at least has a hard time optimizing the code to use them because there a no good parallel annotations.

You should probably try to use a native libary and call it with JNI.

Answer (score 0):

If you know `y`, maybe you can decompose it into a multiplication of smaller numbers, and compute powers of powers. For instance, if `y = 6` you could do

```
y = 2 * 3
power = pow( pow(x, 3), 2)
```

Don't know if it will be faster though.

Comment: I'm sure that would be slower because of multiple powers.

Comment: Even if the "pow" function is redeveloped to take prime decomposition into account? I would say knowing that beforehand could speed things up

Comment: Potentially. I don't know how to do that, though, hence my question :)